# How to create two primary keys in one table using laravel migration?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to define 02 primary keys in this migration, also need to define them in the model class. I m using laravel 9 version. When I define this. it gives the following error.

```
Schema::create('salaries', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id')->primary();
            $table->unsignedInteger('emp_no')->primary();
            $table->foreign('emp_no')->references('id')->on('employees')->cascadeOnDelete()->cascadeOnUpdate();
            $table->integer('salary');
            $table->date('from_date')->primary();
            $table->date('to_date');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Output

```
 SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1068 Multiple primary key defined (SQL
: alter table `titles` add primary key `titles_id_primary`(`id`))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way, here is my e.g:

```
Schema::create("kitchen", function($table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('restaurant_id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->unique(['restaurant_id', 'name']);
});
```

Comment: it seems Laravel do not provide composite primary key option . so i used your way. any way thanks

Comment: Sure, have a good one.

Answer (score 1):

try this for a composite primary key

```
Schema::create('salaries', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('emp_no');
            $table->foreign('emp_no')->references('id')->on('employees')->cascadeOnDelete()->cascadeOnUpdate();
            $table->integer('salary');
            $table->date('from_date');
            $table->date('to_date');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->primary(['id','emp_no','from_date']);
        });
```

Or you can make necessary fields unique if it works for you

Comment: Failed. it gives same error - "Syntax error or access violation: 1068 Multiple primary key defined...."